# How to changing camera or hotspot positions in Aframe

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am a newbee to `A-Frame` and `Javascript`. I went through the `360gallery` code on the `A-Frame` blog and tweaked it.

What I need is:  If I am standing at a particular position in the skybox, I have set 3 hotspots

1. at where I am standing
2. and 3. the position of the hotspots I would like to go and which will switch another texture on the skybox and simultaneously change my position to that selected hotspot. A kind of virtual tour.

What I have achieved until now is the texture of the skybox changes as I see or select a hotspot.

But the position is where I am stuck and need help with.

Comment: Improved grammar, spelling and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Don McCurdy's [library for aframe checkpoints](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/master/examples/checkpoints/index.html) might be helpful for you. You can add the attribute `checkpoint` to the hotspot-entities, then by clicking them, the camera will fly to the hotspot. If the camera should stop before the hotspot, so that it's still visible, then you can add an offset (in this example 5m).

```
  <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v4.1.2/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>

  <a-entity id="rig" movement-controls="controls: checkpoint" checkpoint-controls="mode: animate" position="0 1.6 0" >
    <a-entity id="camera" camera
              look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: true"
              position="0 0 5" <!-- camera will stop 5m (on z-axis) before the checkpoint -->
              camera-listener>
      <a-entity cursor="fuse: true"
                position="0 0 -1"
                geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03;"
                material="color: #CCC; shader: flat;"
                visible="false">
        <a-animation begin="click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" dur="150"
           fill="forwards" from="0.1 0.1 0.1" to="1 1 1"></a-animation>
        <a-animation begin="cursor-fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" dur="1500"
           fill="backwards" from="1 1 1" to="0.1 0.1 0.1"></a-animation>
      </a-entity>
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>

  <a-sphere checkpoint position="-10 1.6 8" color="white" material="emissive: white" radius="0.2"></a-sphere>
  <a-sphere checkpoint position="0 1.6 0" color="white" material="emissive: white" radius="0.2"></a-sphere>
  <a-sphere checkpoint position="-10 1.6 0" color="white" material="emissive: white" radius="0.2"></a-sphere>
```

Comment: i really appreciate for your help, thankyou very much :), i will add it to the code and reply you back